# How to share screen using react agora uikit?

Tags: reactjs, agora.io

I am trying to create a group video calling application using react-agora-uikit but it only provides only camera video sharing. How do I share screen?

Answer (score 0):

To enable screen-sharing in the Agora React UIKit for web, you need to see the  RTC Prop for `enableScreenSharing` to `true` when you add the `<AgoraUIKit />` component to your project.

Your `<AgoraUIKit />` component should look something like this:

```
<AgoraUIKit
    rtcProps={{
      appId: '<Your Agora App ID>',
      channel: 'test',
      token: null, 
      role: isHost ? 'host' : 'audience',
      layout: isPinned ? layout.pin : layout.grid,
      enableScreensharing: true // enable screen-sharing
    }}
    rtmProps={{ username: username || 'user', displayUsername: true }}
    callbacks={{
      EndCall: () => setVideocall(false)
    }}
  />
</>
```

For reference: You can see the [full context in the example](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/VideoUIKit-Web-React/blob/5e5a770c001f26d61d68810e7576677b2281cbfb/example/src/App.tsx#L35) code.